# Can't select 'twitter' and 'twitter-api' in tags

Tags: bug

On SO, when I try to tag a post with `twitter-api`, after typing `twitter`, the `twitter` tag description comes up with at the end the "also" suggestion: `twitter-api`.

However, I can't select `twitter-api`.

I use the latest Chrome update, not a browser problem I think.

Answer (score 4):

[twitter-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-api) is a [synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/twitter/synonyms) for [twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter).

> The following tags will be remapped to [twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter)
>
> [twitter-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-api)

So you can't use [twitter-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-api) as a tag because it would just get remapped.

You noted that you saw twitter-api in the suggestion list, but it's not what you expected.

[image]

That "also" section is not a link by itself, the whole tile is one selection. Clicking on the "twitter-api" text just selects the twitter tag.

Comment: I cant believe my eyes. i havent noticed that till date? ouh...

I thought with first glance, that was only happening to me with "s" plural additions, but havent noticed for different string till now. thanks.